# rubyoverflow 0.5

Tags: library, ruby

### About

[rubyoverflow](https://github.com/danmcclain/rubyoverflow) is an ruby wrapper for the Stack Exchange API.

### Status

Middle of being rewritten. Handles /users/{id}/* routes along with /sites and /users.  Documentation forthcoming

#### Known Issues

Not completed

#### Documentation

Coming soon

#### License

Released under the [MIT Open Source License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Download

```
gem install rubyoverflow
```

or [GitHub](https://github.com/danmcclain/rubyoverflow)

#### Platform

Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3

### Contact

rubyoverflow contains contributions from Dan Seaver. Leave feedback and bug reports on my GitHub [project page](https://github.com/danmcclain/rubyoverflow).

### Code

Complete source can be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/danmcclain/rubyoverflow).

### Notes

Documentation of how API methods map to rubyoverflow coming shortly

### Release Notes

#### 0.5

Begins Rewrite

Comment: I like the get_next_set idea. Wish other wrappers used it.

Comment: @George: Thanks, I am looking to add things to my wrapper that will make it stand out

Comment: @phsr: Mind if others use this idea :)

Comment: @George: If you voted up this library, its fine by me :P.  Seriously, go ahead, the vote would be appreciated though (if you haven't voted it up already)

Comment: @phsr: I voted it up. (Even though I don't use Ruby.)

Comment: @phsr: Please consider posting rubyoverflow on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this wrapper is no longer supported?

Comment: @marcamillion: Actually, quite the contrary, I am in the middle of rewriting it, because shortly after the launch of the official API, this wrapper was broken.

Comment: Is this still working/being developed?

Answer (score 2):

Its funny how some of the rubyoverflow's sourcecode is incredibly similar to pilha.

http://github.com/phsr/rubyoverflow/blob/master/lib/rubyoverflow.rb

http://github.com/dlt/pilha/blob/master/lib/pilha.rb

Why not send pull requests to pilha instead of making your own version of it?

Comment: This is no longer the case, as that was the old repository (I have renamed my github account) and also have began rewriting the wrapper from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Its not bad to borrow someone else's code since you give credit to the person you borrowed the code from. ;-)

The class << self its a shortcut to define a lot of class methods, so instead of doing something like:

```
class MyClass
  def MyClass.a_method
  end

  def MyClass.another_method
  end
end
```

You can do:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    def a_method
    end

    def another_method
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand what class << self does, its why the init_class! works the way it does.  I don't get that I can call Rubyoverflow::Client.config &block once and it keeps the api information set throughout.

Comment: init_class! set a @client variable in the eigenclass of the Base class. All classes that inherits Base can access the @client var in their eigenclass.